# What does ギスる mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, words, slang

Conversation goes:

> A: まだひきずっていたのか
>
> B: え、お前忘れたの？**ギス**ってたの俺だけ？びっくりする
>
> B: 次はねぇぞ

The ギス I know means having a cold atmosphere or strained relationship. But here, I am not sure I get what it means.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Japanese.

As you said, **ギスギス** means having a cold atmosphere or strained relationship even if it is a stranger, a slight friend, or a best friend.

In the same way, "**ギスってる**"　means a relationship gets strained.

The difference between "**ギスギス**" and "**ギスってる**" is "**ギスギス**" just represents the state of strained atmosphere or relationship
while "ギスってる"　means a relationship gets a strained atmosphere　or relationship.

Though there's not enough context to explain the conversation I'll try to:
"**ギスってたの俺だけ？**" means B had thought "A must be having grudge against me even now" until A said I don't mind it now. B realized it was actually different.

Translated:

> A: Then, Are you feeling sorry about it even now?
>
> B: So don't you mind it , do you?

Alternatively, there might be another explanation:
B had been hurt by A. It was a long time ago, so A didn't think B was holding a grudge against them in the present. And so A said "まだひきずっていたのか".

It is often used in informal relationships, especially in online gaming.

Used like this:
"ギスギスした"
"ギスるのが怖い"
"ギスった"

As often happens in Japanese, nouns are often used as verbs when used with "**する**", "ってる","してる" and so on.

(Thanks a lot for correcting my English)

Answer (score 1):

[**According to 若者言葉辞典{わかものことばじてん｝**](https://bosesound.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-906.html)，aka words or slang especially for Japanese young people,

ギスる is defined as,

> ギスるとは、人間関係がうまくいかない、ギスギスすること。
>   主に、コミュニケーションが円滑にいかないとき、不仲になったときに使う言葉。

Translated

> ギスる means "The human relationship gets stiff". Mainly used when the 2-3 more people's
>   relationship got too severe to communicate with each other.

So the OP's "questioner" is trying to tell the other (player),

> "Am I the only one who already felt we had a harsh relationship regarding communication each other"?

**May be the only probable correct answer is A hadn't been giving darn about the communication with B, B is the only one who is upset in his own world ah, sort of having his self-presumption A has too the same edge against B and that's the reason why "B" said, "there is no next, A!".?**

Have a nice day.

Comment: By the way, I saw [this](https://meaning-book.com/blog/20180908114030.html)

So could he also be saying if he was the only one who had a misunderstanding between them? 

by war did you mean like they had a fight?

Comment: @ShaniceAkizakura Your link is providing the same meanings. Yes, as a whole, he noticed he was the only one who had the misunderstanding. But it looks like I need more context.

Comment: Before this B says that A must discuss things with him and not just decide things by himself. B continues to say that since he entrusted his life to A, there should be no secrets between them to which the conversation continues where A answers the one above. Should I type it out starting from there?

Comment: @ShaniceAkizakura Discussion? Life? I'm sorry I can't comprehend what you try to mean since there are no contexts. Why I asked you to provide with more contexts is I don't understand A's last message "次はねぇぞ” "There is no next" which makes me wonder what A tries to imply with his words. So may be a bit more context will be clearer.

Comment: Oh! OMG. Since the panel just has bubbles and dialogues with no people in it,  in addition to me not getting the previous line... I think I switched the speaker. It's B who continued 次はねぇぞ and then the panel shows him stomping away. Sorry about that. Did that help???

Comment: maybe he means by there should be no next time that A just goes off and deciding things by himself without discussing the matter to him and keeping it a secret since he won't let it slide the next time??? I'm thoroughly confused still.

Comment: @ShaniceAkizakura Uhm...well...sorry to say like this. But your update further confused me. B said the last word? If that is so, I have no idea what the B's intention is by the message, meaning why B is being outraged by the communication stuff and I am sorry I can't help you anymore since I am not  Einstein may be "something" must be happening between A and B regarding stuff XXX?

Comment: I am not entirely sure either what's happening with them with this conversation or as to why he suddenly got pissed after saying it cuz he was just complaining that A should talk to him first before doing anything(in general). I guess B was still hung up about something that previously happened. Oh well. Thank you so much for your patience. I really appreciate it. If I encounter the same word, I hope it has a clearer context.